# Как получить значения только определенных input'ов?

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть форма с нескольким input'ами. Передается GET'ом. Мне нужно получить значения только pos1, pos4, pos15. (Это в качестве примера. В действительности их может быть сколько угодно, под разными цифрами.) Или, можно сказать, вывести их в отдельный массив. Может, что-то вроде этого сделать: `$_GET['pos[0-9]{1,}']`? Но так не работает. Спасибо за помощь.

```
<input name="in_comment" value=""> Комментарий<br>
<input name="in_payer" value=""> Плательщик<br>

Услуга <input name="pos1"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos1"><br>
Услуга <input name="pos4"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos2"><br>
Услуга <input name="pos15"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos2"><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@vitaan](/users/23096/vitaan), а почему бы не группировать элементы в самой форме?

```
<input name="in_comment" value=""> Комментарий<br>
<input name="in_payer" value=""> Плательщик<br>

Услуга <input name="pos[1]" value="a"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos[1]" value="1"><br>
Услуга <input name="pos[4]" value="b"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos[2]" value="2"><br>
<!-- Обратите внимание, у вас sum_pos2 в этом месте перезапишет предыдущее значение -->
Услуга <input name="pos[15]" value="c"> Сумма <input name="sum_pos[2]" value="3"><br>
```

---

Массив будет примерно такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [in_comment] => ""
    [in_payer] => ""
    [pos] => Array
        (
            [1] => "a"
            [4] => "b"
            [15] => "c"
        )
    [sum_pos] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Круто! Человеческое СПАСИБО!, то что нужно. А sum_pos2, да, я когда выкладывал, его видимо забыл исправить. Спасибо

Comment: @vitaan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Костыль1:

```
function reget($regexp){
  $out = '';
  foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
    if(preg_match($regexp,$k)){
      $out[] = $v;
    }
  } 
  return $out;
}

$arr_of_values = reget('pos[0-9]{1,}');
```

Костыль2:

Назвать их не pos1, pos2, а всех одинаково: pos[].
Перед отправкой дизейблить ненужные.

Некостыльного метода, пожалуй, нет.

P.S.

вместо {1,} лучше писать +

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.